# Why does StructuredArray need to be non-constructible?

Tags: java, arrays, struct, collections, java-9

[This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju2xsbJ07ug&list=PL2ekzZZrxVUmBXtrwS7pLabUu8v-FCE8O&index=5&t=34m) at 34:00 describes the design of `StructuredArray`s for Java. Everything's rather clear, except for on thing:

It shouldn't be constructible, i.e., the instance may be only obtainable by some *static factory method* like [newInstance](http://objectlayout.github.io/ObjectLayout/JavaDoc/org/ObjectLayout/StructuredArray.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-long-). At the same time, they should be subclassible, which means that there must be a public constructor and the non-constructibility will be assured at runtime. This sounds very hacky, so I wonder *why?*

I'm aware about the advantages of factories in general and static factory methods in particular. But what do we get here, so that it makes the hack acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of the `StructuredArray` class is that someday it can be replaced with an intrinsic implementation that allocates the whole array, including the component objects, as one long block of memory.  *When this happens, the size of the object will depend on the number of elements and the element class*.

If `StructuredArray` had a public constructor, then you could write `x = new StructuredArray<>(StructuredArray.class, MyElement.class, length)`.  This doesn't seem to present any problem, except that in *bytecode*, this turns into a `new` instruction that allocates the object, and then a *separate* `invokespecial` instruction to call the object's constructor.

You see the problem -- the `new` instruction has to allocate the object, but it *cannot*, because the size of the object depends on constructor parameters (the element class and length) that it doesn't have!  Those aren't passed until the constructor call that follows sometime later.

There are ways to around problems like this, but they're all kinda gross.  It makes a lot more sense to encapsulate construction in a static factory method, because then you just *can't write* `new StructuredArray...`, and the JVM doesn't have to use any "magic" to figure out how much memory to allocate in the `new` instruction for `StructuredArray`, because there just can't be any such instructions*.

If some later JVM wants to provide an intrinsic implementation of the static factory that allocates a contiguous array, then it's no problem -- it gets all the information it needs in the factory method invocation.

NB* - yes, OK, technically you *can* write `new StructuredArray...`, but it doesn't make a useful object for you.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter, yes it's easy to intrinsify constructors, but the allocation is already done by the time the constructor is called, so even an intrinsic constructor can't use its size argument to determine the allocation size.

Answer (score 2):

**Semantics** Going through the API documentation my understanding is that it is a question mostly of Semantics. And providing a Fluent API. Also if you go to the conclusion slide of the presentation you should notice that the Semantics bullet comes first (if we don't count the source code url).

If we pick the normal Arrays. They present a clear semantics of:

- Type of the array
- length of the array
- type of the elements

**As a result**

We have a unified model of working with arrays. And the API is crystal clear. There are no 10 different ways of working with arrays. I believe that for the Java language developers, this cleanness of the api is of extreme importance. Forcing the non-contructability they are implicitly forcing us to use the API the way they want us to use it.

**Construction**

Since the StructuredArray essentially is array as well. Presenting a constructor will immediately force us to use the Concrete implementation of the StructuredArray which automatically will create problems introducing this unified model of **"What exactly is an "Array?"**.

This is why going through the Javadoc we can see the way the StructuredArray is actually contructed:

```
  static <S extends StructuredArray<T>,T> S newInstance(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup lookup,
 java.lang.Class<S> arrayClass, 
 java.lang.Class<T> elementClass, 
 java.util.Collection<T> sourceCollection)
```

What is visible here is that the StructuredArray is forcing several things:

1. It is forcing all client classes to work with "StructuredArray" and not with the concrete implementation.
2. StructuredArray is essentially immutable.
3. The immutability means that there is a strict notation of Length.
4. Structured Array has a source of elements. Which once consumed may be disposed.
5. And similarly to the regular Array, the Structured array has a concept of TYPE of elements.

I believe that there is a very strong notation of semantics and also the authors are giving us an excellent hint in how exactly the coding is supposed to happen.

Another interesting feature of the structured arrays is the ability to pass a constructor. Again we are talking about a strong decoupling of the interface and the API from the actual implementation.

**Array Model**

My words are further confirmed by examining the **StructuredArrayModel**
http://objectlayout.github.io/ObjectLayout/JavaDoc/index.html?org/ObjectLayout/StructuredArray.html

```
StructuredArrayModel(java.lang.Class<S> arrayClass, java.lang.Class<T> elementClass, long length)
```

Three things are visible from the constructor:
- Array class
- Type of the elements
- length

Observing further the constructs that the Structured Array supports:

> ```
> An array of structs: 
> struct foo[];
>
> A struct with a struct inside: 
> struct foo { int a; bar b; int c; };
>
> A struct with an array at the end: 
> struct foo { int len; char[] payload; };
> ```

It is fully supported by the **StructuredArrayModel**
In contrast to the StructuredArray we have the ability to instantiate easily concrete implementations of the model.

StructuredArray presents us the ability to pass pseudo constructors http://objectlayout.github.io/ObjectLayout/JavaDoc/org/ObjectLayout/CtorAndArgs.html

```
newInstance(CtorAndArgs<S> arrayCtorAndArgs, java.lang.Class<T> elementClass, long length)
```